# fetch data from database for specific web pages

Tags: php, ajax, html, pdo

I am creating a website in which people can post some thing with expiry date. And i am storing all data in database with expiry date so on pages only valid data will be appeared and expired wont show on pages. Currently I am using this php script

```
    <?php
$servername = "******";
$username = "********";
$date=date("Y/m/d");
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=******", $username, "*******");
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query = "select id, item1, item2, item3, expirydate, description from table WHERE expirydate>= ?";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(array($date));
        foreach($statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
            echo"<div class='col-md-12'>";
                echo"<div class='agent-item'>";
                    echo"<div class='row'>";
                        echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
                            echo"<img src='img/uploads/$row[item1]' class='img-responsive' alt=''>";
                        echo"</div>";
                        echo"<div class='col-md-6'>";
                            echo"<h6 class='mb-xs'>Description</h6>";
                            echo"<p>'$row[item2]'</p>";
                        echo"</div>";
                        echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
                            echo"<p>address</p>";
                        echo"</div>";
                    echo"</div>";
                echo"</div>";
            echo"</div>";
        }
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

The Problem is that fetchAll fetches all data which i really don't want. I want to show 10 items per pages so i want to fetch 10 items and when user clicks next page so on page 2 i want to fetch next 10 items and show them on page 2. I am struggling for 2 days to achieve this but i failed every time even though i tried only fetch() method as well but it iterates only once in foreach loop.
Can some one help me out how can i fetch only 10 items and on next page how can i fetch 10 more items which should be start after previous 10 items.

> Please note: to track the items, choosing the id is not best choice
>   because expiry date vary, that's mean if id 2 user have expiry date
>   after 1 week so id 3 user have expiry date before that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to fetch only 10 records then add `Limit` in query like this

```
select id, item1, item2, item3, expirydate, description from table WHERE expirydate >= ? Limit 10 ;
```

It will fetch only 10 record that are matching
Check whether your query works proper or not

Next Take a loot at here to create pagination for webage

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_pagination.asp

Comment: thanks for reply but i think u did not understand my question. Pagination is already there I want data from database right after the previous data which i have showed in previous page. If i use limit here then how can i track the data for the further pages that how much i have shown and from where it should start because i have 3000 valid data to show up that's why i want to change fetchAll() to fetch. The reason is that fetchAll can make my webpage slower.

Comment: now you want that when user click on second page it should skip the data that is already displayed in first page..

Comment: for that u can add OFFSET to the query  after limit like this select * from table limit 10 offset 10

Comment: offset will skip records that you enter. in above example it will show data after skipping 10 record, Now all you have to is add 10+ increment every time user clicks next page

Comment: ok i tried it but due to change the page this query does not work. first 10 items renders in home page then next 10 in page1 then page2 and so on... any idea how to tackle this problem ?

Comment: Use ajax of jquery to prevent page from being reload and try to change the specific div's data same coding for all page